# Remove special characters from csv data using Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to remove the specific(e.g. @,&) special characters from csv data using PySpark. I have gone through optimuspyspark(https://github.com/ironmussa/Optimus). However it's removing all the special characters. I want to remove specific special characters from the CSV data using Spark. Is there any inbuilt functions or custom functions or third party librabies to achieve this functionality. Thanks in advance.

Few Links I tried :

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/49802/escaping-double-quotes-in-spark-dataframe.html

Comment: Use regex with a `udf`

Answer (score 5):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

assume you have a simple csv file (2 lines) that looks like this:

```
@A 234, 'B' 225, 'C' !556
@D 235, 'E' 2256, 'F'! 557
```

read csv into dataframe:

```
df=spark.read.csv('test1.csv',mode="DROPMALFORMED",\
                  inferSchema=True,\
                  header = False)

df.show()

+------+---------+---------+
|   _c0|      _c1|      _c2|
+------+---------+---------+
|@A 234|  'B' 225| 'C' !556|
|@D 235| 'E' 2256| 'F'! 557|
+------+---------+---------+
```

use pyspark functions to remove specific unwanted characters

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
newDf = df.withColumn('_c0', regexp_replace('_c0', '@', ''))\
          .withColumn('_c1', regexp_replace('_c1', "'", ''))\
          .withColumn('_c2', regexp_replace('_c2', '!', ''))

newDf.show()

+-----+-------+--------+
|  _c0|    _c1|     _c2|
+-----+-------+--------+
|A 234|  B 225| 'C' 556|
|D 235| E 2256| 'F' 557|
+-----+-------+--------+
```

**if you want to remove a specific character from ALL columns try this**:

starting with the same simplified textfile/dataFrame as above:

```
+------+---------+---------+
|   _c0|      _c1|      _c2|
+------+---------+---------+
|@A 234|  'B' 225| 'C' !556|
|@D 235| 'E' 2256| 'F'! 557|
+------+---------+---------+
```

function to remove a character from a column in a dataframe:

```
def cleanColumn(tmpdf,colName,findChar,replaceChar):
    tmpdf = tmpdf.withColumn(colName, regexp_replace(colName, findChar, replaceChar))
    return tmpdf
```

remove the " ' " character from **ALL** columns in the df (replace with nothing i.e. "")

```
allColNames = df.schema.names
charToRemove= "'"
replaceWith =""
for colName in allColNames:
    df=cleanColumn(df,colName,charToRemove,replaceWith)
```

The resultant output is:

```
df.show()
+------+-------+-------+
|   _c0|    _c1|    _c2|
+------+-------+-------+
|@A 234|  B 225| C !556|
|@D 235| E 2256| F! 557|
+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I want to apply the regexp to all the columns(as there are 100's of columns and schema varies frequently) without specifying the column name. Any suggestions please.

Comment: you are welcome. I have added some code that allows a character to be removed from all columns in a data frame - hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With Optimus you can:

`df.cols.replace("*",["a","b","c"]," ").table()`

- Use the start to select all the columns.
- Pass an array with the elements you want to match
- The char that will replace the match. Whitespace in this case.